# Padding with precalculated space in python

Tags: python, padding

In C# I would this:

```
string num1 = "15000";
string num2 = "800";

int a = num1.Length;
int b = num2.Length;
int required_space = a - b;

string input_space = new string(' ', required_space -1);

Console.WriteLine(num1);
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", input_space, "+", num2);
```

And I would get :

```
            15000
             +800
```

last digit aligned no matter the length of num1.

How do I do that in Python?

Comment: You can create a string with the right number of spaces using `' '*(required_space-1)` The rest is just standard `print` calls, which I'm sure you get from an introductory python tutorial.

Comment: Yeah I got it, since it's double space I had to do    '    ' * (required_space-2 )'.  Thank you @AChampion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`string.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rjust#str.rjust) to right justify the second number using the width of `num1`:

```
num1 = '15000'
num2 = '800'

print(num1)
print('+{}'.format(num2).rjust(len(num1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 40, 50, 100, 9001, 10]
max_len = len(str(max(numbers)))

for number in numbers:
    print(f'And the number is: { number :>{ max_len }} !')
```

`f''` is a special string literal that supports most of formatting options described here: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: Note: `f` strings are new in 3.6; you can't count on support being available everywhere yet.